# Scapy Exception: Bad condition in format string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte, python-3.6, scapy

I have this packet sniffer I made:

```
from scapy.all import *
def decode(rawload):
    #still trying to figure out how to decode the payload
    return str(rawload) #temporary
try:
    sniff(iface = "wlan0", filter="host 192.168.1.13", prn=lambda x:x.sprintf("src: %IP.src% (%Ether.src%) receiver: %IP.dst% load: {}".format(decode(x.payload)))) #Error right here
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit(1)
```

And the error I get is `"Scapy Exception: Bad condition in format string: []"`. Could anyone explain what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of your `.format()` call is not a valid string for Scapy `Packet.sprintf()` (probably because of the content of `rawload`.

I guess it contains `{` and `}`, which are used in `.sprintf()` for conditions (see `help(Packet.sprintf)`).

I'd suggest that you replace your code with something like:

```
prn=lambda pkt: pkt.sprintf("src: %IP.src% (%Ether.src%) receiver: %IP.dst% load: ") + decode(x.payload)
```